# Where (the directory) should I put my newly created module in the kernel?

Tags: linux, compiling, kernel-modules, directory-structure

I have created new module code. And want to compile it for my kernel. But I am not sure about I thing. Should I copy it to some designated directory before I start the compilation? Or I can just compile it wherever I want?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anywhere special the source code needs to be. Normally it'd be wherever your repository is.

If you want to leave it somewhere for the next admin to find, the most obvious place would be a company VCS server. `/usr/src` would also be a reasonable place to look, as well as `$HOME`.

Eventually, if you decide to submit the module for inclusion in the kernel, you'll have to put it in the proper spot in your linux git checkout.